# Regex to find a string containing more than a single whitespace with no leading/trailing whitespace

Tags: java, regex

Currently i have

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\s");
    boolean invalidChar = p.matcher(text).find();
```

I want it to return true only when i have more than a single whitespace. 
Also there should not be any whitespace in the beginning or ending of string.

So some valid/invalid text would be

```
12 34 56 = valid

ab-34 56 = valid

ab    34 = invalid

     12 34 53 = invalid
```

Comment: You will need to escape your backslashes in string literals in Java. `\\s\\s`

Comment: is the empty string valid?

Comment: Great question. I forgot to add empty string not valid.

Comment: In this case, try the pattern: `(?<!\\S)(?!\\S)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(^\s{1,}|\s{2,}|\s$)
```

Final:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^\s{1,}|\s{2,}|\s$)");
```

Comment: Add `System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\s{2,}").matcher(item).find());`

Comment: This does not check for whitespace at the start/end of string. See https://ideone.com/eZHBcN where `" 12 34 53"` does not match the `\s{2,}` pattern while the string is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Without regex..

```
public class Answ {

    public static boolean isValid(String s) {
        return !s.contains("  "); //two white spaces
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st1 = "12 34 56";

        System.out.println(isValid(st1));
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be two or more.

Comment: This does not check for whitespace at the start/end of string.

Comment: @Saad Never mind. If there is two white spaces, you can add 1K white spaces, and get the right answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How come? If I understood the question properly (before editing), whenever the String contains at least two white spaces in the row, the 'valid' becomes false...

Comment: @zlakad The original question already contained *Also there should not be any whitespace in the beginning or ending of string.*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's very easy to accomplish that condition calling the method `trim`.

Comment: @zlakad `trim` removes the leading/trailing whitespace, it does not check. You would have to add a temporary variable to see if it is not the same as the original variable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **Totally agreed** !

Answer (score 1):

Since there can't be whitespace at the start and end of the string, and there cannot be two or more consecutive whitespaces inside, you may use

```
boolean isValid = s.matches("\\S+(?:\\s\\S+)*");
```

This expression will match the following:

- `^` (implicit in `matches` that anchors the match by default, i.e. the whole string must match the regex pattern) - the start of the string
- `\S+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespaces
- `(?:\s\S+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\s` - a single whitespace
  - `\S+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespaces
- `$` (implicit in `matches`) - the end of the string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2WNXIZ/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)(?!\\S)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

boolean invalidChar = m.find();
```

or `boolean isValid = !m.find()`, as you want.

Where `(?<!\\S)` means *"not preceded by a non-whitespace"* (that includes a preceding whitespace or the start of the string) and `(?!\\S)` *"not followed by a non-whitespace"* (that includes a following whitespace or the end of the string).

These two lookarounds describe all possible cases:

- successive white-spaces *(matches the position between the first two white-spaces)*
- white-space at the beginning or at the end
- empty string

Comment: No clue who did it.

Comment: Probably someone without idea.

Comment: I have a question. Currently my regex             
 var expireRe = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
is accepting beginning and trailling whitespaces. How can i not accept it? It doesnt except whitespaces if they are in the middle of the string, such as te<space>xt.

Comment: @Saad: it is strange, `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` doesn't accept any whitespaces everywhere in the string. But perhaps the problem comes from the way you define your `isValid` or `isNotValid` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean invalidChar = text.matches("\\S(?!.*\\s\\s).*\\S");
```

Explanation:

`\\S` - the match begins with a non-whitespace character

`(?!.*\\s\\s)` - negative lookahead assertion to ensure there are no instances of two whitespace characters next to each other

`.*` - matches 0 or more of any character

`\\S` - the match ends with a non-whitespace character

Note: the `matches("regex")` method returns true only if the regex matches the entire `text` string.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but there are two things to note: 1) `.*` may not match across lines without a DOTALL modifier, and 2) the expression requires at least 2 chars with two `\S` patterns.